# Quoted search on Stack Overflow Jobs isn't exact search

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, search

I want to search for an exact match on a two-word phrase on Stack Overflow Jobs. I tried wrapping my query in double-quotes and single-quotes, but these return the same results.

Query: `climate change` ......... --> [24 Results](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=climate+change&location=chicago%2C+il&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles)

Query: `"climate change"` .....   --> [24 Results](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=%22climate+change%22&location=chicago%2C+il&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles)

Query: `'climate change'` .....   --> [24 Results](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=%27climate%20change%27&location=chicago%2C%20il&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles)

Worse still, most of the results I clicked on do not even include the term `climate`, and only include the `change` term.

Comment: Does it say somewhere that quotes will perform a literal search? If not, I think this might be a [tag:feature-request] instead of a [tag:bug].

Comment: Hmm, fair point. I've changed it to feature-request. thanks!

Comment: I just found out the Stack Overflow help center [actually mentions this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching). However, I don't know if this applies to the jobs search as well.

Comment: Here's the relevant part of @Hexaholic's link:  "*To find a specific phrase, or to search a string of special characters, enter it in quotes: like `"flat tire"`, or `"<%#"`.*"  I think Jobs search should be consistent with that, especially since quoted phrases are so familiar for search interfaces that they're more or less an [affordance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance) now.

Comment: Your search query returns 0 for me

Comment: @Hexaholic Given that most search engines we know nowadays perform a literal search when quoted it's at least non-intuitive.

Comment: @dan-klasson You can see the same thing with any other search terms in Jobs. e.g. with no location, there are 970 results for both `"full stack"` and `full stack`.

Comment: @Hexaholic Yes, I'd seen that, but couldn't find a reference on the Jobs site specifically. But after reading kdbanman's comment, I am changing this back to a [bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) because I agree it should be consistent with other StackOverflow pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We're currently running an A/B test that exposes these kinds of searches to y'all. You're probably not on the side of the test that allows it.

I'm checking for regressions in the experiment now and assuming all is well I'll be switching it on for all in the next couple of days.

Thanks for the report!

UPDATE: We've now flipped to the side of the experiment that makes this the default behaviour.